# do I need to use volatile if update to other thread'cache is not time-constraint

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, volatile

I have a singleton object with one method:

```
class static single
{
  String static somefileContent;
   public static void set(String str){somefileContent=str;}
   public static String get(){return somefileContent;}
}
```

and I have two thread,

one thread query the content from single.get() in operations, about 100 times/sec.

and another thread monitor some file to update the string with set() method in period,  if the file get modified,refresh  the content.

it is acceptable few operation use the old string value.

my question is: should I need the volatile ,because it is not time-constraint?

if worst happen, whether the read thread do not get update forever?

I just wondering what would happen to use plain Java? yes, the read thread may read old value after the value get update. but like I said, read old value for few times is acceptable. I wondering whether the old value stays forever in the CPU cache.

and Thanks to Vaspar's answer.

Comment: Why don't you run a few times and see for yourself ? ;)

Comment: why don't you synchronize the get/set methods

Comment: @alfasin "Run a few times" is terrible advice for figuring out concurrency edge cases.

Comment: @chrylis true, but in this case he'll get a consistent behavior (hint: his so called 'worst case')

Comment: @alfasin he may get consistent behavior on his local x86 but if he tried to port it to ARM anything can change.  That's why it's a terrible idea.

Comment: @JohnVint and the likelihood if that is... 

Comment: Non zero.  I get your point, it's just not a reasonable approach when considering multi threaded programming.

Comment: True, that's not the right approach for dealing with concurrency issues, but in this case... 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better use [ReentrantReadWriteLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html) and you don't need to use volatile variable. The `get` call should be ReadLocked which is shared, and the `set` call should be WriteLocked which is exclusive. The changes are updated in all the threads once they all get their respective ReadLocks.

> All [ReadWriteLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html) implementations must guarantee that the memory
>   synchronization effects of writeLock operations (as specified in the
>   Lock interface) also hold with respect to the associated readLock.
>   That is, a thread successfully acquiring the read lock will see all
>   updates made upon previous release of the write lock.

Sample Code:

```
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock.ReadLock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock.WriteLock;


public class Single {
    private static String                       somefileContent = null;
    private static final ReentrantReadWriteLock readWriteLock   = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
    private static final ReadLock               readLock        = readWriteLock.readLock();
    private static final WriteLock              writeLock       = readWriteLock.writeLock();

    public static String get() {
        try {
            readLock.lock();
            return somefileContent;
        } finally {
            readLock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public static void set(String str) {
        try {
            writeLock.lock();
            somefileContent = str;
        } finally {
            writeLock.unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the ReadWriteLock is permitted solution. 

I just wondering is it acceptable to use plain Java?

yes, the read thread may read old value after the value get update.

but like I said,read old value for few time is acceptable.

I wondering whether the old value stays forever in the CPU cache.

Comment: you're welcome. This lock design is meant for frequent readings and not-so-frequent writings. Also, every "read", after the modification, is guaranteed to see the update. Volatile variable or Atomic objects, also serve the purpose, if the operation is just to swap a single variable. If you want to do a bunch of steps, then, locking is the best way.

Comment: If you want to use plain java, without volatile/atomic objects, the thread which has read an old value will never see the new value unless the thread does an `action` that has a "happens before" relationship. For eg: synchronization or something like that. Only then, all the variables are refreshed. If the thread doesn't have such an action, it will *never* see the update at all.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/memconsist.html https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html#MemoryVisibility - Further reads. In the case of locks that I mentioned, they are `actions` satisfying **happens before** relationship. Hence, updates done by the writer threads are visible in the reader threads.

Comment: thank you , the happens before relationship is the exactly answer to my question.